# SAP - CALL REPORT RCS11001

Tags: abap

I have to create a new custom report and I need to call the standard report RCS11001 in my report custom. How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - voting for close since this question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If the report has a transaction code, you can also use the statement

```
call transaction <transaction> 
   using         <table with bdc instructions> 
   options from  <structure with execution parameters>
```

This way, you can pre-define entries for the selection screen, if there are.

You can use tcode SHDB to get the bdc instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SUBMIT** for calling any report.

```
SUBMIT report WITH param IN range.
```